How to convert RAW column with Java-Object-Streams to plaintext VARCHAR2
I am working in a project where in the past they have chosen to store lists of country codes as a Java-Object-Stream using the RAW datatype in the Oracle DB.
So for example, ['AW'] would be saved as 0xACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B470200007870000000017400024157 in the database.
And e.g. ['SE','DK'] would also be saved as something similar.
We feel this setup isn't optimal for us because we often check the DB when debugging and it isn't precisely the most human-friendly reader friendly format. In addition, we have plans for future sql scripts where we need to operate and make comparisons on this column, which is very restricted when using the RAW datatype.
So how would I go about this problem?

We already have a script which, given the RAW data, spits out the corresponding plaintext string.
I've researched online that utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2() could be of use, but I'm not sure how I would use it in this context.
I've already tried a "normal" update but = doesn't work with the RAW datatype so the following script didn't work:

UPDATE my_table
SET country_codes = '[AW]'
WHERE country_codes = '0xACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B470200007870000000017400024157';

I just want the column to contain "plaintext" strings, and the datatype should be varchar2 or similar. And then I will make sure to adjust the application logic afterwards.
Before



id
country_codes [RAW]




1
0xACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B470200007870000000017400024157


2
0xACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B47020000787000000001740002444B


3
0xACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B47020000787000000002740002444B7400025553



After



id
country_codes [VARCHAR2(255)]




1
[AW]


2
[DK]


3
[DK, US]




Broadly, try opening an ObjectInputStream on ResultSet::getBinaryStream. Here's me doing it for ZonedDateTime - you have an easier case: try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {while (rs.next()) {Blob b = rs.getBlob(4);if (b == null) {System.out.println("ZoneDateTime was null");continue;} else {try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(b.getBinaryStream())) {ZonedDateTime zdt = (ZonedDateTime) in.readObject();System.out.printf("Value of ZonedDateTime was %s%n", zdt);}}}}

Hi @g00se would you mind posting your comment as an answer? It is quite difficult to read as a comment  hehe

Do you really want to store multiple values as an array of quoted strings (e.g. ['SE','DK'] in a varchar2 column, rather than normalising to a separate table with one value (e.g. SE) per row?

@AlexPoole I totally agree with you. Unfortunately this is what has been decided as the quickest and easiest change. Fortunately there aren't many country codes (even in the worst case) where it would be a performance/storage issue, the most country codes per entry I've seen in PROD was like 3-4.

It will still make it harder to read and handle in your future SQL scripts, and even a nested table type would be easier. but, OK... From your attempt it looks like you want (or are happy) to brute-force all the known combinations - so you'll have a second update for whatever the RAW version of ['SE','DK'] is? (Your example RAW seems to be Svensk?)  It would be tricky to get useful values from the RAW I think, you'd have to interpret the streams format, so if you don't have many combinations, that may be acceptable. But - if the column datatype is RAW you can't update it to a string.

@AlexPoole I've updated my question (and nice catch btw). I think you're maybe overcomplicating it a bit . We're not considering any combinations or considering any duplicates. Everything is allowed and there can be any strings in here (hence why you by my misstake also saw 'Svensk'). Step 1 is to convert the column into a proper datatype, step 2 is to clean up the data and add user validation etc. But that is for another question another day :)

I'm confused then (clearly!) - if you've got a script (Java program?) that converts the RAW value from your table to the string you want, why can't that also update a new column in your table using that string? Why do you need to look at utl_raw to convert the RAW value?

If that's what you've got, here is an example of deserializing a different class that you can use:
try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        Blob b = rs.getBlob(4);
        if (b == null) {
            System.out.println("ZoneDateTime was null");
            continue;
        } else {
            try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(b.getBinaryStream())) {
                ZonedDateTime zdt = (ZonedDateTime) in.readObject();
                System.out.printf("Value of ZonedDateTime was %s%n", zdt);
            }
        }
    }
}



I've already tried a "normal" update but = doesn't work with the RAW datatype

It does, but only if you're comparing the data types properly. You are doing:
WHERE country_codes = '0xACED...4157';

Oracle will try to implicitly convert the data to make the comparison work:

During SELECT FROM operations, Oracle converts the data from the column to the type of the target variable.

So it will convert the RAW column value to a string, and compare that with the string you gave, and they won't match.
You are using a string representation of your value from your client or application, which has prepended it with the 0x marker to show it's a hex string; but Oracle's rawtohex() function does not do that, and that's what it will use for the implicit conversion. So you are really doing, for the row that should match:
WHERE 'ACED...4157' = '0xACED...4157';

which doesn't actually match and therefore no rows are updated.
If you explicitly convert your string representation - without the 0x part - then it won't do any implicit conversion and will match:
WHERE country_codes = hextoraw('ACED...4157');

fiddle - which also displays RAW values with 0x, unless you explicitly convert them with rawtohex().
You can either do that manually for every value, using the values produced by your script; or if it's already hitting the database to get and decode the RAW  values, that could also do the updates.

Here is how I see this:

You decided once to store some Java array data in the database. In the DBMS you didn't care what the content meant, it was just binary data your apps would store, read and interpret.
Now you want your DBMS to be able to understand the data, so you can use it in your SQL queries. As the content is an array, you need an additional table to store the 1:n reference. This you will be able to read and filter your data based on the content with SQL.
You seem to have made a further decision to store a value list in a single column, so you can very easily store and read the list from your app, but any query with a where clause on the data will be slow and more prone to errors.

I think that that final decision is a wrong move. If you want to work with the data in a relational database, then store the data in a relational format, i.e. in a normalized database.
But no matter whether you'll store relational data or just some string like '[DK, US]', the way to get this done is the same:

Read the data with a Java app, because this app understands the format.
Have your app store the data in a readable form in the database.


Okay so I managed to come up with a solution/strategy that worked for me. Thank you @AlexPoole for informing me about removing the 0x hex prefix when checking for equality!
-- 1. Add temporary column
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD country_codes_tmp VARCHAR2(255);

-- 2. Populate new column with converted data from old column
UPDATE my_table SET country_codes_tmp = '[no]' WHERE country_codes = 'ACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B470200007870000000017400026E6F';
UPDATE my_table SET country_codes_tmp = '[BOL]' WHERE country_codes = 'ACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B47020000787000000001740003424F4C';
--- ...

-- 3. Drop old column
ALTER TABLE my_table 
DROP (country_codes);

-- 4. Rename temporary column to original column name
ALTER TABLE my_table
RENAME COLUMN country_codes_tmp to country_codes


That looks...quite worrying ;). If the column contains Java serialized data then why not do this in Java so you don't have to tear down your table?
